# Entity Framework throws invalid column name User_Id error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, orm, foreign-keys

I am trying to create and associate the entities in my project. The User can have many Roles, Claims and Logins. On the other hand, A claim or login can have only one user, while a role can also be with many user. I have the relationship defined with fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Claims).WithRequired(cl => cl.User).Map(m => m.MapKey("User"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<Claim>().HasRequired(cl => cl.User).WithMany(u => u.Claims).Map(m => m.MapKey("User"));

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Logins).WithRequired(lg => lg.User).Map(m => m.MapKey("User"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<Login>().HasRequired(lg => lg.User).WithMany(u => u.Logins).Map(m => m.MapKey("User"));

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithMany(ro => ro.Users).Map(userRoles => 
    {
        userRoles.ToTable("Users_Roles");
        userRoles.MapLeftKey("User");
        userRoles.MapRightKey("Role");
    });     

    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasMany(ro => ro.Users).WithMany(u => u.Roles).Map(userRoles => 
    {
        userRoles.ToTable("Users_Roles");
        userRoles.MapLeftKey("User");
        userRoles.MapRightKey("Role");
    }); 
}
```

As you see, my database tables do not follow Entity Framework's convention, instead of using 'User_Id' as foreign key, the foreign key is simply named 'User'. However, I keep getting this 'Invalid Column Name: User_Id' exception message.

I tried to define the foreign key column name with the above code by calling the methods Map() and MapKey(), but with no prevail. Why is this happening? Am I writing the mapping code wrong? Can someone help?

PS: The exception error message is very unhelpful that I do not know which table this column name error is associated with. Does anyone know how to make the exception message show what the table name is, not just the column name? Thanks.

Also I've added code I used for Claim, Login and Role entities(with unrelated methods removed).

```
public class Claim
{
    public string Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Type { get; protected set; }
    public string Value { get; protected set; }

    public virtual User User { get; protected set; }

    public Claim() { }

    public Claim(string id, User user, string type, string value)
    {
        Id = id;
        User = user;
        Type = type;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class Login
{
    public string Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Provider { get; protected set; }
    public string Key { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime? DateLoggedin { get; protected set; }

    public virtual User User { get; protected set; }

    public Login() { }

    public Login(string id, string provider, string key, DateTime? dateLoggedIn = null)
    {
        Id = id;
        Provider = provider;
        Key = key;
        DateLoggedin = dateLoggedIn;
    }
}

public class Role
{
    public string Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Title { get; protected set; }
    public string Description { get; protected set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; protected set; }
    public bool IsBanned { get; protected set; }

    public IList<User> Users { get; protected set; }

    public Role() { }

    public Role(string id, string title, string description, bool isAdmin, bool isBanned)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
        IsAdmin = isAdmin;
        IsBanned = isBanned;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your entity model have a User property for the key?  As for the error message, is this a runtime error, or are you using migrations?  If migrations, use the -verbose switch when doing the update to see more details on the error...E.g update-database -verbose.  Finally, without seeing the model class, I question both the ManyToMany maps...You're saying a user has many users...and a role has many roles?  Your user entity has ICollection<User> Users on it?

Comment: @MatthewHilgenfeld: Yes it is a typo, thanks for pointing out, just fixed it. And it is runtime error when I debugged my website and tried to register the user. The User exists as a virtual property for both Claim and Login entities, while for Role entity it is virtual property IList<User>.

Comment: I typically use a Property for the key, and map with e.g. HasRequired().WithMany().HasForeignKey(), but I don't see any issue with the mappings as you have defined.   Is there another entity not shown that has a User property that the convention is trying to define the key for?

Comment: I see. I can use a property for the key, but then I will have to define the column name somehow unless I want a different convention. And nope, I dont have another entity with a 'User' property defined. I think if I can at least identity which table this invalid column name error corresponds to, I can move closer to the solution. Right now it can be with any tables, its more confusing.

Comment: @MatthewHilgenfeld: Now that you mention it, I realize that all my properties are protected(not public), and I have constructors for all entities. Could this be a problem? I edited the original post to include entity definitions for the three entity classes other than User.

Comment: AFAIK the protected properties are fine, as long as they have a getter and setter.  The entities are required to have a parameterless constructor, but it may be protected/private, but you have that, so there is no issue there.

Comment: I see. I think maybe its because I forgot to define User as a parameter in the constructor of Login entity, is this a problem? Also do you know how I can get more information from the exception details? It only tells me invalid column name, but doesnt even tell me which table.

Answer (score 0):

The User_Id column is being created by EF convention because you map your key to a property by the same name as your navigation proeprty.

You could either remove the .Map() part and let EF handle the key, or define a key property on your Claim and Login classes, and map that in the fluent api. I would personally do the latter.

E.g:

```
public class Claim
{
public string Id { get; protected set; }
public string Type { get; protected set; }
public string Value { get; protected set; }

public virtual User User { get; protected set; }
public int UserId{get;set;}
public Claim() { }
}
```

And in your ModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(a=>a.Claims).WithRequired(a=>a.User).HasForeignKey(a=>a.UserId);
```

If you create a key field of 'EntityNameId' (UserId, ClaimId, etc) then EF convention will automatically map that as your Foreign Key, without the fluent mapping.  However, if you name is something else (UsernameId, or whatever), you have to explicitly provide the mapping.  [Some reading on that.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)

Comment: umm I see, so in EF you cannot define the column name/foreign key name to be the same as navigation property name? I have to rename it to UserId?

Comment: Correct, if you define the key column yourself (by .Map) it cannot have the same name as the navigation property.  I prefer the last approach because then the Key becomes a property on your model class you can reference in your application.  And I prefer the explicit definition.

Comment: I see, got it. After re-defining the column name to be UserId instead of User, the error goes away. I am getting a different error now, it says "The navigation property 'Claims' declared on type 'User' has been configured with conflicting mapping information.". I am trying to fix this now.

Comment: Nope it was a mistake from me, dont worry about it.

Comment: Sorry actually I still get the same error even after I renamed the columns. I am totally lost now...

Comment: What do you mean by rename the columns?  You added a property to your model class...or you renamed a column in the DB?   Are you doing DB first, or code first?

Comment: Well I am doing code first. I renamed the column to UserId, and changed the mapping to 'UserId' rather than 'User', same error...

Comment: Did you add a property to your model for the ID?  Did you update the mapping to use HasForeignKey instead of Map()?  Also, the article I posted at the end should give plenty of examples...did it help?

Comment: Well right now I have switched to your suggestion, to add UserId as a property in Claim and Login entities, and call HasForeignKey(m => m.UserId). It still gives me error.

Comment: It seems that if I add a column UserId in the User table the problem goes away. No idea why though.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Comment: Well thats not the solution lol. I did find a solution in the end, turns out that I have a property IList<User> Contacts in User entity, which stores a list of contacts. It aint configured yet, but apparently Entity Framework thinks that the user entity needs User_ID column to store this reference(contacts should be many to many, its strange). So I used [NotMapped] annotation on this property and it now works. I guess I will handle the mapping for contacts later, for now I will worry about other things. I am getting another complex type related error, I may post another question. sigh.

Comment: Yup, that why I [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901589/entity-framework-throws-invalid-column-name-user-id-error/39902438?noredirect=1#comment67089409_39901589) :)